# Non-latin symbols in chapter title

Tags: cyrillic, asciidoc, asciidoctor-pdf

I have the following asciidoc source file:

```
:doctype: book
Перший розділ
-----------------
Chapters can contain sub-sections nested up to three deep.
```

The following error comes up:

```
asciidoctor: WARNING: b.txt: line 3: unterminated listing block
M+ 1mn is not a known font.
```

I run it with the following command:

```
asciidoctor -r asciidoctor-pdf -b pdf b.txt -a pdf-style=my.yml -a pdf-fontsdir="/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts"
```

Where my.yml has this content:

```
extends: default
font:
  catalog:
    Times_New_Roman:
      normal: Times_New_Roman.ttf
      bold: Times_New_Roman_Bold.ttf
      italic: Times_New_Roman_Italic.ttf
      bold_italic: Times_New_Roman_Bold_Italic.ttf  
base:
  font-family: Times_New_Roman
```

Apparently, the problem is in Ukrainian symbols. How should I fix it?

EDIT:

This happens only if the chapter title is in Cyrillic, with the body it works fine.

```
:doctype: book
The First Chapter
-----------------
Розділи можуть містити підрозділи.
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=asciidoctor+cyrillic&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us

Comment: Thank you @matt but this is different. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using 4 extra dashes in the document title.

```
Перший розділ
-----------------
```

It should be:

```
Перший розділ
-------------
```

Please note that setext (two-lines) titles are not recommended, instead you should use this syntax:

```
= Перший розділ
:doctype: book

Chapters can contain sub-sections nested up to three deep.
```